# The actual functionality of launch() method

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. Sometimes I see `def launch():` method in the python script, does it imply that this method will be the first one invoked by default, i.e. similar to `main` in C++.

Thank you.

Comment: No function is special in Python.  No function will be executed unless something calls it.

Answer (score 2):

No, `launch()` is nothing special. You may sometimes see this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This checks whether the program is being run as the main program, rather than being called from somewhere else, and then executes that conditional code (running a function called `main()`, in this case).